# How to get android notifications when app was closed?

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

From webserivce I am getting data in the form of dates and time, means for some particular date i am having some set of slots. The following diagram gives the detailed explanation. [image]

Here on each date I have some set to timings. Here what i want is to display notification at the particular date and time. If the response from database consists of tomorrow date like 07/12/2012 at 11:00 AM. I need to display notification at that time.

I have some idea regarding notification manager and code i am using is..

Main.java

```
      NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_action_search, "A New Message!", System.currentTimeMillis());

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, Main.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(Main.this, notificationTitle, notificationMessage, pendingIntent);
    notificationManager.notify(10001, notification);
```

**But here i need to get notifications when app is closed also.** So, anyone help me with this.

Comment: you can write service to do this task :-http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html

Answer (score 21):

Add a (started) `Service` to your application. Even though the user quitted your app, the service will still run in the background.

Furthermore you can implement a BroadcastReceiver that will listen to the phone's Intents and let your service be started when the phone boots !

**MyService.java**

```
public class MyService extends Service {

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
    // START YOUR TASKS
return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // STOP YOUR TASKS
super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent){
    return null;
}
```

**BootReceiver.java**

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent("your.package.MyService");
            context.startService(serviceIntent);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

// in manifest tag

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

// in your application tag

```
<service android:name=".MyService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="your.package.MyService" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>

<receiver
    android:name=".BootReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true"
    android:label="BootReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

If you want to start your service from an activity, just use

```
private boolean isMyServiceRunning() {
         ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
         for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
             if (MyService.class.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                 return true;
             }
         }
         return false;
     }

if (!isMyServiceRunning()){
     Intent serviceIntent = new Intent("your.package.MyService");
     context.startService(serviceIntent);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Can you help me with any some sample code. As i new to android developing i am unable to find the code related to your answer.

Comment: Edited. When it comes to what to do inside the task you could use AlarmManager, ScheduledExecutorService, etc. You should look at android.developer or global Java docs about ways to display events are specific times.

Answer (score 7):

If data comes from your server then utilizing [GCM](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html) might be good approach. In this case server will have ability to wake/start your application.

Creating a service which is constantly running in your case is a crappy solution.
IMO better approach is use of [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html). Alarm manager will invoke intent on specific time. (note that if phone reboots you have to register intent again).