# What is the best (most efficient) way to show notifications when the app is closed?

Tags: java, android, notifications

My app is basically is a schedule app, where I'd like to show notifications x minutes before an (user-set) event occurs.
I read the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html), but it only covers showing a notification at the time the notification code is being executed (which I guess is the only way).

My guess is that if I want to have notifications show up even when my app is closed, I need to somehow make the app run in the background and constantly check for upcoming events, calculate the time left, and show a notification when the time left equals the time before the event the user chose to be notified at.

I read this question (+answers): [How to get android notifications when app was closed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13741875/how-to-get-android-notifications-when-app-was-closed).

There is a pretty detailed answer (using services) I could simply implement, but the other answer claims this approach is "crappy".
The second answer also suggest the usage of `AlarmManager` which, after reading the doc, doesn't sound that bad (executing code at a specific time).
However, since I'm targeting API19 it's "inexact" (according to the doc).

So what exactly **is** the most efficient (and the right) way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement alarm manager with service. Set the time user chose and show notification at that time. The sample shows a Toast, you can use notification/sound/dialog, anything.
Check out [this](http://khurramitdeveloper.blogspot.com/2013/06/android-alarm-manager-to-start-service.html) sample.