# Android push message is not received if gcm registration tokens are swapped

Tags: android, android-intent, google-cloud-messaging, push, registration

On my Android device,

I am

1. Installing my application (Old install) and sending push from the server. I can receive push on my device.
2. Remove the old install and Installing my application again (new install) on the same device, and send push from the server. I can receive the push message.
3. In the backend server, I am replacing registration id of old install
   with new install's registration id.
4. Now when I try to send push message to old install,

I am expecting the new install to receive the push message. Instead, I get the following warning message in logcat and my push notification is suppressed.

> W/GCM-DMM(1641): broadcast intent callback: result=CANCELLED forIntent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE pkg=com.pushping.xxx (has extras) }

Why is the broadcast canceled in this situation? I believe, with the right registration id I should be able to send the push message to the corresponding install.

Comment: What do u mean by old install and new install?

Comment: Check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39480931/error-broadcast-intent-callback-result-cancelled-forintent-act-com-google-and) if it can help you.

Comment: @RanjanK.M.  I am calling Install created using step 1 as the old install.  and Install created using step 2 as new install

Comment: @KENdi. Nopes thats not the issue. Thanks anyways

Comment: @Anurag fcm sends notification only to those id which are currently registered with devices. But when you install again, new id is registered with the device so the old id is of no use.

Comment: @RanjanK.M. When you say "fcm sends notification only to those id which are currently registered with devices", is firebase tracking uninstalls? I guess not as i am getting that logcat on the device which means device can receive push message and gcm client is suppressing it . I will put my question in other words, Assuming I have registration id and project number and server key of the new install, is it possible for me to send a push message to that device from another push service (not firebase). If not that whats blocking it?