# App doesn't show firebase notifications (broadcast intent callback: result=CANCELLED forIntent)

Tags: android, json, firebase, logcat, firebase-notifications

I can't receive my Firebase Notifications when the app is killed or in background.

I signed the APK, and it doesn't work, and when I send my Data notification with JSON the logcat shows me this error:

```
   broadcast intent callback: result=CANCELLED forIntent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE pkg=com.example.paolomazza.firebasedemo3 (has extras) }
```

Given the following Manifest, what could be the cause of this bug?
Thanks in Advance

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <receiver android:name="com.example.paolomazza.firebasedemo3.OnBootBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name=".FirebaseIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.paolomazza.firebasedemo3.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"
                android:stopWithTask="false" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"
                android:stopWithTask="false" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application>
```

And here's the code for showing the notifications

```
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();

    //you can get your text message here.
    String text= data.get("my_custom_key");

    System.out.println(text);
    notifies(text);
}

private void notifies(String body){
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(MyFirebaseMessagingService.this)
                    .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_help)
                    .setContentTitle("Congratulations!")
                    .setContentText(body);
    Notification mNot= mBuilder.build();
    NotificationManager mNotMan = (NotificationManager)
            getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotMan.notify(1,mNot);
}
```

Comment: <action android:name="com.example.paolomazza.firebasedemo3.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" replace this line by <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" and remove this line android:stopWithTask="false"

Comment: No, when the app is killed in my Android phone it doesn't show the notification. I sent a JSON data notification!

Comment: Can you post your notification generate code where you create you notification in which activity?

Comment: for sure, I post it in the first message!

Comment: I am not talking about that first message I am talking about the notification generate code when you get the Json payload and the you generate the notification.Did you implement above solution and tried which I was posted.

Comment: Sorry, I mean I wrote my code in the main message here on this post in stack Overflow!

Comment: Problem is in your notification generate code. You are not using the pending intent in that.Please [see this link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)

Comment: You can also refer this stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13902115/how-to-create-a-notification-with-notificationcompat-builder)

Comment: No, I put the pending intent and when the app is killed it doesn't show the notification (on my adb instead yes). ON my two physical phones I use Marshmallow as OS. The logcat is always the same

Comment: Please check any application in your phone don't restrict the notification this happens in many devices now a days. Also make sure you have to allow notification for the application.For that go to app info inside check the notification section.

Comment: Already checked, the app is allowed to send notifications

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/a/58162451/7579041 this

Answer (score 3):

OK, I just solved the problem.

If you're using a Huawei device, or a device that uses a EMOI os, just go to

> Advanced settings

than go to

> Battery

and

> Protected Apps

than select your app, switch it on and you'll be able to receive your notifications in the background!