# How to reliably run location tracking services on brands like Oppo, Vivo, Xiaomi?

Tags: android, service, autostart, xiaomi, oppo

I work for a cab company which specializes specifically in intercity and outstation rides. This means that we have to track the driver for long duration, continuously. our app works fine on stock android phones but how do I keep my location service active on OEMs like Oppo, Vivo, etc.

Almost 70% of our user-base uses one of these devices so blacklisting these devices isn't an option. Is there any reliable solution? I'm in desperate need of it.

I saw a old question here related to the same issue. I've searched around the internet and one solution (unreliable) I found was to fire a intent which leads to the autostart setting of the phone.  This does not work on all of their devices, and also not all drivers are smart enough to turn on this setting.

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/58162451/7579041

Comment: Please take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59442078/background-services-are-restricted-in-xiaomi-and-oppo)
In this devices background services are restricted. You must white-list your app.

Comment: use foreground service