# Background service is stoped when application is killed from stack

Tags: java, android

Background service is stopped when application is killed from stack

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .build();

    return START_STICKY;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct solution but there is workaround mentioned in below link,

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58162451/7579041

above link is useful for Stock ROM & Custom ROM Devices like OnePlus, OPPO, VIVO, etc

I hope this will help you out

Answer (score 0):

Go to App info And Give Auto start permission for your app.
if you want take programetically this permission then .

```
    public class Utils {

public static void startPowerSaverIntent(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences("ProtectedApps", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean skipMessage = settings.getBoolean("skipProtectedAppCheck", false);
    if (!skipMessage) {
        final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        boolean foundCorrectIntent = false;
        for (Intent intent : Constants.POWERMANAGER_INTENTS) {
            if (isCallable(context, intent)) {
                foundCorrectIntent = true;
                final AppCompatCheckBox dontShowAgain = new AppCompatCheckBox(context);
                dontShowAgain.setText("Do not show again");
                dontShowAgain.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                        editor.putBoolean("skipProtectedAppCheck", isChecked);
                        editor.apply();
                    }
                });

                new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                        .setTitle(Build.MANUFACTURER + " Protected Apps")
                        .setMessage(String.format("%s requires to be enabled in 'Protected Apps' to function properly.%n", context.getString(R.string.app_name)))
                        .setView(dontShowAgain)
                        .setPositiveButton("Go to settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                context.startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, null)
                        .show();
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!foundCorrectIntent) {
            editor.putBoolean("skipProtectedAppCheck", true);
            editor.apply();
        }
    }
}

private static boolean isCallable(Context context, Intent intent) {
    try {
        if (intent == null || context == null) {
            return false;
        } else {
            List<ResolveInfo> list = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent,
                    PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
            return list.size() > 0;
        }
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

Add this for defferent device

```
public class Constants {
//updated the POWERMANAGER_INTENTS 26/06/2019
static final List<Intent> POWERMANAGER_INTENTS = Arrays.asList(
        new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.miui.securitycenter", "com.miui.permcenter.autostart.AutoStartManagementActivity")),
        new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.letv.android.letvsafe", "com.letv.android.letvsafe.AutobootManageActivity")),
        new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.huawei.systemmanager", "com.huawei.systemmanager.optimize.process.ProtectActivity")),
        new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.huawei.systemmanager", Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P? "com.huawei.systemmanager.startupmgr.ui.StartupNormalAppListActivity": "com.huawei.systemmanager.appcontrol.activity.StartupAppControlActivity")),
        new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.coloros.oppoguardelf", "com.coloros.powermanager.fuelgaue.PowerUsageModelActivity")),
        new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.coloros.oppoguardelf", "com.coloros.powermanager.fuelgaue.PowerSaverModeActivity")),
        new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.coloros.oppoguardelf", "com.coloros.powermanager.fuelgaue.PowerConsumptionActivity")),
        new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.coloros.safecenter", "com.coloros.safecenter.permission.startup.StartupAppListActivity")),
        Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N ? new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.coloros.safecenter", "com.coloros.safecenter.startupapp.StartupAppListActivity")).setAction(Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS).setData(Uri.parse("package:"+ MyApplication.getContext().getPackageName())) : null,
        new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.oppo.safe", "com.oppo.safe.permission.startup.StartupAppListActivity")),
        new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.iqoo.secure", "com.iqoo.secure.ui.phoneoptimize.AddWhiteListActivity")),
        new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.iqoo.secure", "com.iqoo.secure.ui.phoneoptimize.BgStartUpManager")),
        new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.vivo.permissionmanager", "com.vivo.permissionmanager.activity.BgStartUpManagerActivity")),
        new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.asus.mobilemanager", "com.asus.mobilemanager.entry.FunctionActivity")),
        new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.asus.mobilemanager", "com.asus.mobilemanager.autostart.AutoStartActivity")),
        new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.letv.android.letvsafe", "com.letv.android.letvsafe.AutobootManageActivity"))
                .setData(android.net.Uri.parse("mobilemanager://function/entry/AutoStart")),
        new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.meizu.safe", "com.meizu.safe.security.SHOW_APPSEC")).addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT).putExtra("packageName", BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID)
);
}
```

Permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="oppo.permission.OPPO_COMPONENT_SAFE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.huawei.permission.external_app_settings.USE_COMPONENT"/>
```