# onTaskRemoved() not getting called in Oppo devices

Tags: java, android, oppo

OnTaskRemoved () not getting called in Oppo devices, When app removed from recent list of apps and also the service not running when the app in the background and the screen get locked.

Answer (score 0):

As Oppo has Custom Android ROM they have provided their custom battery optimization methods,

There is no direct solution but there is workaround mentioned in below link,

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58162451/7579041

above link is useful for Stock ROM & Custom ROM Devices like OnePlus, OPPO, VIVO, etc

I hope this will help you out