# How to receive notifications after close app?

Tags: android

I have an android application made by android studio. I know how to get data from my server through socket with Socket.IO and how to show notifications. I want to show notification from this app even after I close the app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get android notifications when app was closed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13741875/how-to-get-android-notifications-when-app-was-closed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question is not very clear but,

I think **background services** is what you are looking for. Check these out.

[Official Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html)

[Vogella Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html)